# Parse json with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I have been trying to use SwiftyJSON for my dummy JSON file inside the project.

But i could only get "null" or "nil" instead of data in JSON file. I might ask for little assistance here.

this is what i get as response : 
0
null
Name of 1 : nil
Make of 1: null

Here is dummy JSON file ;

```
{
    "Cars": [

        {
            "Name": "111",
            "Make": "2000"
        },    

        {
            "Name": "222",
            "Make": "2010"
        }

    ]

}
```

and here is where i tried to parse ;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOfRows = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()

    }

    func parseJSON() {

        let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonfile", ofType: "json") as String!
        let jsonDATA = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData! 

        let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonDATA, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

        let allList = readableJSON["Cars"]

        numberOfRows = readableJSON["Cars"].count

        print("\(numberOfRows)")

        print("\(allList)")

        let name1 = readableJSON["Cars"][0]["Name"].string
        let make1 = readableJSON["Cars",0,"Make"]

        print("Name of 1 : \(name1)")
        print("Make of 1: \(make1)")

    }


}
```

Comment: Pass an `NSError` instance as error parameter to get some error information. `as String!` is a very unusual syntax. Either use `as! String` or optional binding (preferable) `if let … as? String { …`

Comment: I got that --> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.})

Comment: The JSON string might end with a \0 terminator which causes the error or the JSON is not encoded properly. Since the JSON text is in a file remove all space characters which are only human readable syntactic sugar.

Comment: PS: The JSON is basically correct. Check if there are any invisible control characters at the end of the file.

Comment: you are right vadian. I had some other writings as comment ( /* .....  */ ). The problem solved after i have removed all garbage at the end. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will help you.

```
func parseJson () {

  if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonfile", ofType: "json")
    {
        if let jsonData = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        {
            let originalJson = JSON(data: jsonData)
            for (_, subJson) in originalJson["Cars"] {
                print(subJson["Name"])
                print(subJson["Make"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```